# How to do redirect control to another folder in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not much familiar with structure of Spring MVC, but I need to resolve it.

Following is spring code which is already in system.

In JS

```
load('../Finance/create/user.do',
```

IN Java

This controller have `@RequestMapping("/Finance/*")` on top and following is post method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "create/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String openDialogBox(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    List<UserType> type = UserService.getUserType();
    model.addAttribute("usergroup", someobject);
    model.addAttribute("userTypes", type);
    return "/common/User/UserDialog";
}
```

The response goes to /common/User/UserDialo.

This "common" is other folder lying with "Finance" folder is located in View and in which UserDialog.jsp is located.(Actually some files were in Finance and I need to take them in common to make it reusable but controller adjustments I am not familiar with much)

There is no controller with name "common".

What changes I need to do in code that control jumps to /common/User/UserDialog? If anything unclear please ask.

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to render the response with another view? (just change the string you return to match the path of the view) Does your code throw errors or behave in unexpected ways?

Answer (score 2):

As you say:

> *The response goes to /common/User/UserDialo.*

This is because your function `openDialogBox()`:

```
return "/common/User/UserDialog";
```

This return value is *view name*.

And I bet that you have `viewResolver` bean in your configuration file. For example a bean like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
           </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
</bean>
```

As you will see above, each "returned value" (view name) is decorated in this way:

> prefix + view name + suffix = /WEB-INF/pages/WelcomPage.jsp

The source of this example: [Mkyong Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-example/).

Comment: @fatherazrael Does it answer your question? Can you accept it for me?